# ransomware removal bootable rescue CD / USB

Tags: malware, bootable

My friend's computer with Windows OS is infected by ransomware and I am going to make a bootable CD/USB to remove the ransomware .

I found two programs, but non of them are up-to-date:

https://falconfour.wordpress.com/tag/f4ubcd/

http://www.hirensbootcd.org/

Do you know any more up-to-date program?

I have both windows and Linux and there is no limit on payed or free program.

Comment: I also found http://www.deftlinux.net/about/ but I am not sure if it is capable of removing malwares from windows. what do u think?

Comment: Anything based on WinPe should do AS it is able to turn a Windows install CD into a Boot environment

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with free Kaspersky Rescue Disk: http://support.kaspersky.com/us/viruses/rescuedisk#downloads